# Xamarin/Maui: accelerometer giving unexpected readings

Tags: c#, xamarin, maui

My .NET Maui app, running on Android, listens for accelerometer events so I can detect the phone being dropped onto a hard surface. When I test dropping the phone onto a cushion, the highest reading I'm seeing (9.7) is very close to the highest seen when dropped onto a wooden floor (10.3), but I was expecting the wooden floor to trigger significantly higher readings. Can anyone explain why this is?

```
public class AccelerometerLogger : IAccelerometerLogger
{
    private readonly IAccelerometer _accelerometer;
    private readonly ILogger<AccelerometerLogger> _logger;
    private SensorSpeed _sensorSpeed;

    public AccelerometerLogger(IAccelerometer accelerometer, ILogger<AccelerometerLogger> logger)
    {
        _accelerometer = accelerometer;
        _logger = logger;

        _accelerometer.ReadingChanged += Accelerometer_ReadingChanged;
    }

    private void Accelerometer_ReadingChanged(object sender, AccelerometerChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        LogMagnitude(e.Reading.Acceleration.X, e.Reading.Acceleration.Y, e.Reading.Acceleration.Z);
    }

    private void LogMagnitude(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        double magnitude = Math.Sqrt(
            x * x +
            y * y +
            z * z);

        _logger.LogInformation($"SensorSpeed.{_sensorSpeed}, Magnitude {magnitude}, X {x}, Y {y}, Z {z}");
    }

    public void Start(SensorSpeed sensorSpeed)
    {
        _sensorSpeed = sensorSpeed;

        if (!_accelerometer.IsMonitoring)
        {
            _accelerometer.Start(_sensorSpeed);
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        if (_accelerometer.IsMonitoring)
        {
            _accelerometer.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

**Cushion max reading**
SensorSpeed.Fastest, Magnitude 9.747349162873507, X -5.737298011779785, Y -0.9130182266235352, Z 7.826916694641113

**Wooden floor max reading**
SensorSpeed.Fastest, Magnitude 10.394357445992371, X 6.888028144836426, Y -7.085226535797119, Z 3.224484443664551

Comment: Does the event trigger multiple times when the impact happens? 
Would landing on a soft surface have more gradual slowdown with more event triggers while landing on hard surface would trigger less times with higher changes in the values?

Comment: Yes the event fires many times, approx 500/second, and there is a more gradual slow down on the cushion. I could write some logic to account for this to distinguish between a soft or hard surface. I was surprised to not see a more significant difference in overall magnitude though, but maybe I'm wrong to assume there would be?

Comment: I think you’re making some bad assumptions.  I’d suggest downloading an app that display raw sensor data and using it to establish baselines for different use cases, and then checking if MAUI produces the same results.  That and researching (maybe ask on the physics SE site) how to detect hard vs soft landings

Comment: See https://www.monodaq.com/applications/2-smartphone-accelerometer-vs-high-end-iepe-vibration-measurement/ for comparison of smartphone to high end accelerometer. Scroll down to phone drop. I would have expected the phone to show a better spike than it does. IIRC the problem is that for accuracy, it is necessary to limit the frequency response (of any measurement system, not just acceleration) to half the sample rate. The spike is so much shorter than the sample time, that almost all the energy is smoothed by the frequency filter. The total energy over three samples will be roughly correct.

Comment: A second limiting factor is that the hard impact g-force is well beyond what the sensor can output. The fact that soft and hard landings give values close to each other suggests that may be what you are seeing. These factors combine.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, thanks. Yes it seems the accelerometers in modern phones don't run fast enough or read high enough. I have noticed that it takes longer for a impact on a cushion to complete, and less time on a hard surface, so I'm going to approach it from a duration perspective, rather than G.

Comment: @pevecg, yes, it takes longer to slow down when landing on a cushion. I'm going to tackle this from a duration perspective instead.

Comment: @Jason, I have now tried your suggestion; Maui does produce readings in line with those from a downloaded sensor app. The problem seems to be the accelerometer not being accurate enough.

Comment: The ratio between the spike and its immediate neighbors might be a useful metric. Given spike at `data(i)`, formula could be `d(i) / avg(d(i-1), d(i+1))`, where `avg(a,b) = (a + b) / 2;`.